# How to download file from website

Tags: python, http, download, httprequest, python-requests

This is my first question, so please be nice if I am, in any way, doing it wrong.

I am using the requests module in python 3.3 to automate file downloads from a few sites, but [this one](https://gats.pjm-eis.com/gats2/PublicReports/RenewableGeneratorsRegisteredInGATS/) in particular is giving me trouble when I attempt to get the csv file. I have a workable level of competence in python but am unacquainted with html and javascript as far as website interaction is concerned.

Here is the relevant code.

```
import requests
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

folder = 'some path'

url = 'https://gats.pjm-eis.com/gats2/PublicReports/RenewableGeneratorsRegisteredInGATS/'#ExportTo'
payload = {'exportType' : 'CSV',
           'tabNumber' : ''}
doc = requests.post(url, data=payload, stream=True)

output = open(folder+now+'_GATSRegistered.csv','wb')
output.write(doc.content)
output.close()
```

I don't get any errors, but the document I am creating is based on an error page. I have successfully done this for a site where the url pointed directly to the file (`'http://www.place.com/path/file.xlsx`), so I know what to do with the file once it's been retrieved. But that simply required a 'get' request.

So, my questions:

- What is the correct request to post?
- Is post even the right thing to do?
- Is this a special case or something I should know how to address in general?
- Anything else I should be doing differently?

Comment: Post is for sending data to the server, get is for just getting it (although it can also send data, but not securely).

Comment: Well, one thing would be to look into Python's `with` keyword to open files.  It closes them automatically.

Comment: @user2387370 When I use get, I just get the original page as if there were no payload. My thinking was that I needed to send some data to let the server know I had "clicked" the CSV button, but are you saying this can be done with get?

Comment: @user41790 get can be used to send data, although I don't know the details for requests. Get sends data by appending it to the url, if you see URLs with &foo=7&bar=8 etc. on the end, that is a get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the page in Chrome and opened the developers console with the network tab open. There you can see that clicking the "CSV" button sends a `POST` request with a lot of form data.

```
exportType:CSV
tabNumber:
CSV_CH:1
PRN_CH:0
GridView$DXFREditorcol0:
GridView$DXFREditorcol1:
GridView$DXFREditorcol2:
GridView$DXFREditorcol3:
GridView$DXFREditorcol4:
GridView$DXFREditorcol5:
GridView$DXFREditorcol6:
GridView$DXFREditorcol7:
GridView$DXFREditorcol8:
GridView$DXFREditorcol9:
GridView$DXFREditorcol10:
GridView$DXFREditorcol11:
GridView$DXFREditorcol12:
GridView$DXFREditorcol13:
GridView$DXFREditorcol14:
GridView$DXFREditorcol15:
GridView$DXFREditorcol16:
GridView$DXFREditorcol17:
GridView$DXFREditorcol18:
GridView$DXFREditorcol19:
GridView$DXFREditorcol20:
GridView$DXFREditorcol21:
GridView$DXFREditorcol22:
GridView$DXFREditorcol23:
GridView$DXFREditorcol24:
GridView$DXFREditorcol25:
GridView$DXFREditorcol26:
GridView_custwindowWS:0:0:-1:-10000:-10000:0:1px:-10000:1:0:0:0
GridView_DXHFPWS:0:0:-1:-10000:-10000:0:180px:100px:1:0:0:0
GridView_DXPagerBottom_PSPSI:2
GridView$DXSelInput:
GridView$DXKVInput:[]
GridView$CallbackState:BwMHAQIFU3RhdGUGEAEHGwcAAgEHAQIBBwICAQcDAgEHBAIBBwUCAQcGAgEHBwIBBwgCAQcJAgEHCgIBBwsCAQcMAgEHDQIBBw4CAQcPAgEHEAIBBxECAQcSAgEHEwIBBxQCAQcVAgEHFgIBBxcCAQcYAgEHGQIBBxoCAQcABxsHAAcABwEHAAcCBwAHAwcABwQHAAcFBwAHBgcABwcHAAcIBwAHCQcABwoHAAcLBwAHDAcABw0HAAcOBwAHDwcABxAHAAcRBwAHEgcABxMHAAcUBwAHFQcABxYHAAcXBwAHGAcABxkHAAcaBwAHAAcAAgAFAAAAgAkCCUVudGl0eUtleQkCAAIAAwcEAgAHAAIBBTaVAAAHAAIBBwAHAAIQRmlsdGVyRXhwcmVzc2lvbgcCAAIIUGFnZVNpemUDBzI=
GridView$DXSyncInput:
GridView_DXFilterRowMenuCI:
DXScript:1_142,1_80,1_135,1_91,14_0,1_90,1_113,14_23,14_10,1_98,1_105,1_77,1_128,1_126,1_124,1_133,1_119,1_127,1_104,1_101,1_84,1_109,1_92,14_1,1_94,1_97,1_95,1_96,1_106,14_4,1_100,1_117,1_103,14_12,14_13,1_102,1_129,1_107,1_137,1_114,14_16,10_2,10_1,10_3,10_4,14_3
DXMVCEditorsValues:{"GridView_DXFREditorcol0":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol1":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol2":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol3":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol4":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol5":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol6":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol7":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol8":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol9":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol10":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol11":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol12":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol13":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol14":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol15":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol16":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol17":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol18":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol19":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol20":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol21":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol22":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol23":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol24":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol25":null,"GridView_DXFREditorcol26":null}
```

You can see which of the above is absolutely necessary for you to send to the server. I doubt all of them are required (but I've been wrong plenty :) ).

That said, when using `stream=True`, you should use `iter_content`. So your code would look like:

```
payload = {
# Form contents
}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, stream=True)
with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        output.write(chunk)
```

The for-loop ensures that as it becomes available it is written to your file. When it is stalled, you won't have to worry about it hanging on you.

Comment: Excellent; this is very helpful. I don't think all of the form data will be absolutely necessary, either, but for proof of concept I am trying all of them first. How do I go about translating the Chrome console view into python/requests? I do not really know what should be an array, list, dict, string, etc.

Comment: It looks like the website is using a unique identifier to prevent pass-through scamming, which has the side-effect of preventing post interaction at this level (I think). Marking this answer as correct, though.